# how to make button stick to one place when resizing window in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jbutton, layout-manager

I am designing a frame in java swing, which has 2 buttons on the end as I resize the window the gap between buttons are spread and they go far. 
Please provide me solution as i want buttons to be in the bottom corner and the frame is resized the spaces should not increase.

Comment: @JarrodRoverson  Given the duplicate depended on *resizing* the component in question (to fit the available space), while this question *implied* the preferred size of the buttons should be respected (i.e. **don't** stretch or resize them) I don't really see this as a duplicate.  As with most layout matters, the devil is in the details.. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the buttons in a right aligned flow layout, then add the flow layout (the panel) to the page end of a border layout.